# Add Current line to a pattern

Tags: notepad

I have a file with 2000 lines.

I want to add the current line number between the ().

For example:

1. c-data (1).json
2. c-data (2).json
3. c-data (3).json
4. c-data (4).json

A screenshot of example test data:

[image]

Comment: Your example seems wrong for lines 3 & 4. Please explain in detail whether the parenthesis already exist or whether your question is adding *space ( line-number )" before the point, and if is there only one point.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry Amended

Comment: Please add an example of what these 4 lines look like *before*.

Comment: @harrymc you can see that on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a super easy idea for you.

1. Use Notepad++ to replace the 5 to nothing:

Search --> Replace --> On Find what field write 5 --> keep empty the replace with field --> Click on replace All, exactly like the next screenshots:

[image: Notepad++]

[image]

2. The second step is to click on the empty area like the next screenshot: 
   [image: empty area]
3. Click on edit --> column editor --> click on number to insert.

[image: column editor]

4. The last step is to replace the spaces with nothing again.
   The result will be exactly what you ask.